# Hand tracking with Intel Perceptual Computing SDK and XNA

Tags: c#, xna, intel, xna-4.0, perceptual-sdk

I am creating a game in C#/XNA. I am using the Intel Perceptual Computing SDK for hand gestures and movements.

I am having a hard time figuring out how I am meant to get a dot to follow my hand. Any help would be grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the C# hand tracking sample in the SDK not adequate for showing proper usage?

Answer (score 0):

Intel has shifted development over to a new version of the SDK, called the Intel RealSense SDK. There is a [RealSense support forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/Forums/realsense) where your question (with more detail supplied by you) might be able to get more traction.